# tensorflow - is this equivalent to mse?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I am very new to TensorFlow, I notice that [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/mean_squared_error) there is `tf.losses.mean_squared_error` which implements the mean squared error loss function.

Before using it, I played around with TF and I wrote

```python
tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(y, y_))))
```

However this gives different results. To me it looks like it is the same formula. What is going wrong?

Are the two formulations different? (and what about `tf.nn.l2_loss`?)

Also, I am trying to do a MLP and I am using a `mse` loss function as input to `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(mse)`. Can this function (`mse = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, y_)`) be used (in a regression problem) also as "accuracy" on the test set by using `sess.run(mse, feed_dict = {x:X_test, y: y_test})`? Or what is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you sum before taking the mean, so you get the squared error and not its mean. Change `tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(y, y_))))` to `tf.reduce_mean((tf.square(tf.subtract(y, y_)))`

```python
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
y = tf.get_variable("y", [1, 5])
x = tf.get_variable("x", [1, 5])
sess = tf.Session()
t = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(y, x))))
t2 = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(x, y)
t3 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.subtract(y, x)))
sess.run(t, {"x": np.ones((1, 5)), "y": np.zeros((1, 5))})  # 5
sess.run(t2, {x: np.ones((1, 5)), y: np.zeros((1, 5))})  # 1
sess.run(t3, {x: np.ones((1, 5)), y: np.zeros((1, 5))})  # 1
```